# "Break-before-make" SPDT Relay out of 2 SPST Relays

Tags: switches, relay

I require a SPDT relay (changeover) that will switch up to 600Vdc, which presents some problems because on the major suppliers such as Digikey, such a product is not readily available at such a high voltage.

However, there are SPST relays available and I was thinking of using two of those. However, I am concerned because I need the contact to the first line to disengage before connecting to the second line (otherwise I might cause a short).

To make things a little more difficult, I have only one digital control signal available, and would like the switch to connect to either one line or the other based on whether I am outputting a logic 0 or logic 1.

Anyways, all this to ask: does anyone have any recommendations for introducing this switching delay via hardware components? I was looking around for a "break-before-make" design but wasn't finding much luck.

Any help or direction would be appreciated!

Edit: Based on the accepted answer here is the schematic I came up with, for reference. Thanks everyone!:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXVNF7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: There is always a good chance that one relay will be faster and make contact before the other breaks contact.

Comment: how many poles you need?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič SPDT implies single pole

Comment: look here, something similar? http://www.schneider-electric.com/en/product-range-selector/664-tesys-d/?parent-subcategory-id=3010

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I think that the operational voltage listed there is at maximum 300VDC, but thanks for the suggestion anyways! I also was thinking more of a PCB-mount solution

Comment: Please see my updated answer for a single-chip logic solution.

Comment: looks kind of dangerous.  why not use diodes to cover the gap instead of shorting the two supplies together.

Comment: @Jasen would you be able to expand a bit more? I am not sure what you mean exactly

Comment: connecting two voltage sources in parallel can make bad stuff happen. especially if there's a fault in one of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Study this circuit: -

[image]

There is a single input called PWM but it can be any on-off circuit from any old logic device. It produces two outputs and notice the little bit of deadband due to the RC network.

For your application you can invert the OR gate output to guarantee it never rises until the AND gate output has gone low for the delay incurred by the RC network AND, importantly the AND output will never go high until the (N)OR output has fallen to low for the same period.

1 input, two outputs with shoot-thru (aka deadband) protection.

As an aside I'd probably use schmitt trigger input logic gates.

Comment: This is exactly the type of thing I was looking for--very useful and clever design. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that won't work since, if the relays are SPSTNO, the circuit's outputs should be out of phase.

Comment: @EMFields I think that's why he mentioned I might want to invert the OR gate output to be a NOR, which would allow them to work with SPST-NO

Comment: @jssoe: Well, the terminology was a bit spotty, in that it's not a question of if you **want**  to use a NOR, since for your application, the NOR isn't optional and that should be reflected by the schematic.

Comment: @EMFields you are right - it's a tad confusing at first but it's the only circuit I had to hand.

Comment: @EMFields good point, I have updated by original question to show visually what was described in text form

Comment: Don't forget you need to make sure your logic gates have Schmitt trigger inputs, so they're OK with the RC input. Alternatively, you could buffer the RC filter input.

Comment: @ConnorWolf - I mention this in my last sentence.

Comment: You could use the circuit as drawn but use the and output to drive the relay with a common-emitter NPN BJT and the or output to an NPN connected common collector for the other relay.

Comment: @ConnorWolf:  The NOR shouldn't need to be a Schmitt trigger if the input edges are crispy, and neither should the AND, since the  RC is essentially a low pass filter and once its output  passes the switching threshold of the AND, what's going to make it back down?  And even if it does glitch, the relay(s) surely won't be able to follow the glitch,  so what's the point?

Answer (score 4):

### update:

Here's Andy aka's circuit, but with the OR converted to a NOR, the AND converted  to its DeMorgan equivalent in order to provide a one-chip solution, and a  simulation run and plotted using LTspice..

His is a nice circuit, and a caveat with these kinds of circuits is that the RC delay **must** be substantially longer than either relay's release time in order to let things settle once the made contacts have opened.

[image]

Comment: Coolio squared LOL!

Comment: BTW what sim are you using?

Comment: @Andy aka: LTspice, [available at](http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/)   and a TTL (74HC actually) [available at](http://groups.yahoo.com/group/LTspice/)